# How to show Image preview using valums uploads in django and also submit the image

Tags: django, jquery, file-upload

I am trying to achieve two things.

1. Show preview of an image chosen by the user. This is basically for the user to validate that he has indeed uploaded the right image. I save the image in a temp location for this.
2. After filling some other data and confirming the image is right. I  want to post this data and the image to a url.

I am using Valum's ajax upload to upload the file and have successfully got the image preview to show.

The problem is how do i submit the entire data: the image about which the user is sure now and some other data(comments, email id etc) now.

The approach I am considering is to use the file uploaded to the server for preview and save it in my database. But I am not very comfortable doing so. Is there a better way to achieve this goal.

Thanks in advance

A small part of my html:

```
          <div id='file-uploader'></div>
          <img alt="Preview" class="previewImage" id='preview' height='50' width='50'/>
          <input type=text id="addLink" size="60"/>
          <textarea name="Name" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea>
          <input type="email" name="emailBox" size="60">
          <div id = 'testlink'></div>
          <input id="submitrequest" class="button" type="submit" value="Submit photo">
```

My Javascript:

```
     uploader = new qq.FileUploader( {
                    action: "{% url ajax_upload %}",
                    multiple:false,
                    element: $('#file-uploader')[0],
                    onComplete: function( id, fileName, responseJSON ) {
                             if( responseJSON.success )
                               $('#preview').attr('src', responseJSON.url) ;
                             else
                               alert('failed') ;
                    },
        });
        $('#addLink').blur(function(){
                    linkTemplate = _.template("<a href='<%= link  %>' value = 'Go to Link' class = 'button'></a>");
                    linkval = $('#addLink').val();
                    if(linkval.startsWith('http://') == false)
                       linkval = 'http://' + linkval;
                    $('#testlink').append(linkTemplate({link:linkval}));
        });

        $('#addLink').focus(function(){
                    $('#testlink').empty();
        });
```